# Why doesn't universality imply existence?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am currently learning the Lean proof assistant, and I had a hard time proving the following implication:
$$\forall x, p (x) \implies \exists x,p(x)$$
I gave up after some time and I decided to do some research instead, but I couldn't find anything on the topic. It seems really strange to me, because obviously if a predicate is true for all x's, then there exists some x which satisfies the predicate.

Thanks.

Comment: "... but I couldn't find anything on the topic."  Lean pickings.

Comment: @mjw Aaarrgh...

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Not much to lean on.

Comment: Every Fields Medalist I know says the statement is false.

Comment: @Acccumulation Every Fields Medalist I know says the statement is true.

Comment: Suppose a variable $x$ ranges over the set of Unicorns. Let B(x)  be the predicate " x eats at least one baby for breakfast". Certainly, B(x) is true for all x ( otherwise, there would  actually exist a unicorn that does not eat at least a baby for breakfast). But that does not imply  that there is actually a unicorn that eats a baby... So, the fact that no unicorn is a non-baby-eater does not imply that there actually exists a unicorn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In first-order set theory** (and first-order logic in general), we always have $$(\forall x. P(x)) \rightarrow \exists x. P(x)$$

However, we do not have $(\forall x \in A. P(x)) \rightarrow \exists x \in A. P(x)$ unless $A$ is non-empty. Why? Because $\forall x \in A. P(x)$ abbreviates $\forall x. x \in A \rightarrow P(x)$, while $\exists x \in A. P(x)$ *does not* abbreviate $\exists x. x \in A \rightarrow P(x)$, but rather $\exists x. x \in A \wedge P(x)$.

If we take $A=\emptyset$, then $\forall x. x \in \emptyset \rightarrow P(x)$ is vacuously true, but $\exists x. x\in \emptyset \wedge P(x)$ is always false, since $x \in \emptyset$ never holds. So the former does not imply the latter, unless $A \neq \emptyset$.

**In dependent type theory**, the underlying formal theory of Lean, there is no direct equivalent to the "unbounded" quantifiers $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ of first-order logic. Whenever one writes `∃ x, p x` in Lean, it's really just an abbreviation for `∃ x : T, p x`, where `T` is some type determined by the type of `p`. For example, if we take `is_even` from the [Lean tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/quantifiers_and_equality.html#the-existential-quantifier), then `∃ x, is_even x` abbreviates `∃ x : ℕ, is_even x`.

So if `α` is a type variable, then proving `(∀ x : α, p x) → ∃ x : α, p x` is not possible: if it was, we would be able to substitute any type, including the `empty` type (see [here](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/inductive_types.html)) for `α`. However, if you fix any inhabited (~non-empty) type, e.g. by setting `α = ℕ`, then you will be able to prove `(∀ x : ℕ, p x) → ∃ x : ℕ, p x`.

Comment: Writing `{  _ : inhabited α }` , where `α` is the type variable indeed makes the proof possible. Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that logics allowing empty domains are called [inclusive logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic).

Answer (score 10):

Everything being a $P$ [doesn't imply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) there is a $P$, as there might not be anything (in the universe we're quantifying over). Universal quantification really tells you certain things *don't* exist - in this case, non-$P$s. For example, we know all odd perfect numbers satisfy [an impressive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) of results, but for all we know there might not *be* any such numbers.

Edit, based on a point @NoahSchweber made: in first-order logic, [we usually insist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_domain) a universe cannot be empty, because it leads to inference-thwarting complications such as this.

Comment: Is that why it was so difficult to prove?  The statement is false!

Comment: Actually, in the usual semantics for first-order logic (which rules out empty universes) the sentence $\forall x p(x)\implies\exists x p(x)$ is **valid** - it's its "relativizations" like "$\forall x\in A(p(x))\implies \exists x\in A(p(x))$" which are not valid in general.

Comment: That said, I don't know how Lean handles it - if Lean allows an empty universe, then you're right.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Whatever Lean does, your observation is definitely worth adding to my answer. I've done so, with the most relevant link I could to substantiate your statement.